# Camera and gallery crop options

Tags: android

I am using camera option in my app but it works some devices only. Also I need crop options.

```
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

        mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
        System.out.println("Gallery Image URI : "+mImageCaptureUri);
        CropingIMG();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix camera issue, I have used following methods

1. CameraIntentHelper
2. onSaveInstanceState
3. onRestoreInstanceState
4. onActivityResult

   ```
   private void selectImage() {

   final CharSequence[] options = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel"};
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PhotoSuiteActivity.this);
   builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
   builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

           if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
               if (mCameraIntentHelper != null) {
                   mCameraIntentHelper.startCameraIntent();
               } else {
                   Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                   String imageFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/picture.png";
                   File imageFile = new File(imageFilePath);
                   picUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile); // convert path to Uri
                   takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);
                   startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
               }
           } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
               Toast.makeText(PhotoSuiteActivity.this, "Not yet Ready...!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                       android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
               // Start the Intent
               startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
           } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
               dialog.dismiss();
           }
       }
   });
   builder.show();

    }

    private void setupCameraIntentHelper() {
       mCameraIntentHelper = new CameraIntentHelper(this, new CameraIntentHelperCallback() {
           @Override
           public void onPhotoUriFound(Date dateCameraIntentStarted, Uri photoUri, int rotateXDegrees) {
               messageView.setText(getString(R.string.activity_camera_intent_photo_uri_found) + photoUri.toString());
               mImageCaptureUri = photoUri;
               Bitmap photo = BitmapHelper.readBitmap(PhotoSuiteActivity.this, photoUri);
               if (photo != null) {
                   photo = BitmapHelper.shrinkBitmap(photo, 300, rotateXDegrees);
                   imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                   CropingIMG();
               }
           }
       @Override
       public void deletePhotoWithUri(Uri photoUri) {
           BitmapHelper.deleteImageWithUriIfExists(photoUri, PhotoSuiteActivity.this);
       }

       @Override
       public void onSdCardNotMounted() {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.error_sd_card_not_mounted), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

       @Override
       public void onCanceled() {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.warning_camera_intent_canceled), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

       @Override
       public void onCouldNotTakePhoto() {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.error_could_not_take_photo), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

       @Override
       public void onPhotoUriNotFound() {
           messageView.setText(getString(R.string.activity_camera_intent_photo_uri_not_found));
       }

       @Override
       public void logException(Exception e) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.error_sth_went_wrong), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Log.d(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
       }
   });
   }
   ```